# Localisation of Ax 2009 morphX reports

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

When printing reports in a locale different to the logged in users locale, the date and currency formats match those of the Windows user account of the the person logged in, not the locale of the report being run.

Is there any way to fix this so a user can be logged in with the Windows locale set to "en-AU" and then print a report in a different locale (i.e. for a customer that speaks Polish) so date and currency fields are in the correct format?

Answer (score 1):

You do not change locale when printing reports. You change the language.
This will not affect date or number formats as you correctly observed.

You have 3 options:

1. Use a neutral formatting like: 2015-12-18
2. Change the report control properties dynamically based on country preference
3. Do your own formatting to string based on value and country

For the second option, it is possible to loop over all report controls of the generated report to do the property change.